# How to understand time-dependent file-system check?

Tags: ext4, fsck

When I configure my `ext4` file-system to perform a file-system check with 1 day interval, then I can see from the output of `dumpe2fs` that this has already passed:

```
# date
Tue Feb  7 01:15:19 EET 2017
# dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda2 | grep -E "Last checked:|Next check after:"
dumpe2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Last checked:             Sun Feb  5 15:44:19 2017
Next check after:         Mon Feb  6 15:44:19 2017
#
```

Now when I reload this machine, I expect a `fsck.ext4` during the boot, but this does not happen and "Last checked" field in `dumpe2fs` output is still `Sun Feb  5 15:44:19 2017`. Then I thought that maybe this `Next check after` means that next file-stem check will not happen before `Sun Feb  5 15:44:19 2017` even if maximum mount count is reached, but that is also not true. In other words file-system is checked if maximum mount count is reached even if `Next check after` is in the future.

How to understand time-dependent ext[234] file-system check?

Comment: Do you have a `1` or `2` as the last (sixth) field in `/etc/fstab` for this filesystem? If not, then only a warning will be given when the filesystem is mounted that an fsck should be performed but it won't be done automatically.

Comment: @wurtel Last(sixth) field is 1.